# How to update TextView from AsyncTask when I recreate the activity

Tags: android, asynchronous, design-patterns, android-asynctask, textview

I have myProgressTextView in MainActivity.
Inside MainActivity I launch a long process using an asyncTask: `MyTask.execute(getApplicationContext(),myProgressTextView)`
Using *publishProgress* and *onPostExecute* I'm able to update myTextView and works all like a charm.

I have a problem navigating between others activities and return back to MainActivity.
Passing again through onCreate of MainActivity myTextView reference is changed and
I'm not longer able to update my UI ( myTextView ) from MyTask that is still running.
What is the right solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, AsyncTask is now deprecated. Google encourages usage of the new **android architecture components**. If you want to persist the information from the task on screen rotation you should consider using ViewModel and Kotlin coroutines. More information for [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) and [Kotlin coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines).

Answer (score 1):

You should cancel all the tasks when the activity goes off the screen i.e onStop().
Async Task is deprecated you can use ViewModel and LiveData approach for handling this scenario as Live data is lifecycle aware.